# VBA Some functions are not working anymore

Tags: excel, vba

I was writing my code when simply some function are not working properly anymore. I have a project and It has a function to copy a archive from a folder to other folder, 3 hours ago it worked properly, now every archive that I copy get corrupted. Same thing happened with another macro that I made to complete a report with some informations, when I execute simply corrupt the file. I'm desperated and I don't know what to do. I've already reinstalled excel, I've already tried to run an old code that I saved for security, same error.

The codes:

```
Private Sub arquivo_reports(line_b, new_add, old_add, opcao)

Dim sheet_ As Workbook
Dim report As Worksheet, informations As Worksheet

If (opcao = 1) Then
    FileCopy old_add, new_add
End If

Set sheet_ = Workbooks.Open(new_add, False, False)
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set report = sheet_.Worksheets("reports")


 sheet_.Close SaveChanges:=True
 End Sub



Public Sub fill_creport()

Dim line_complain As Integer
Dim path As String
Dim sheet_report As Workbook
Dim report As Worksheet

path = FileOpenDialogBox()

Set sheet_report = Workbooks.Open(path, False, False)
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set report = sheet_report.Worksheets("report")

line_complain = 4 + Application.Match(report.Cells(1, 21).Value, Range("A5:A600"), 0)


End Sub
```

Comment: You didn't include the part of your code that calls the `arquivo_reports` function so we can see how you come up with the arguments. And there doesnt seem to be a value set to `opcao` either.

Comment: do you get an error? have you degugged? what line is causing the problm?

Comment: are macros not working in all the workbooks, or just this one? If just this one then file might have gotten corrupted and you should copy its contents to a new one

Comment: I don't get any error, but after I run the first function It corrupts the file of the question and the second function makes the workbook disappear after I run, so I have to close without saving to not lose the workbook.

These functions are called by a custom userform.

The macros is not working in none sheet.

Comment: Now I notice the error is given when I open the workbook and save the changes after. Does anybody know why this is happening?